# Servlet filter (autologin) precedence over declarative security checks

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, jsf-2, servlet-filters

**Short question**. How is it possible to execute servlet filters before any declarative security check is performed?

**Long question**. For my web application I'm trying to manage all my security needs using server declarative security: I have set a security constraint on `<url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>` with `<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>` and `<form-login-page>/sign-in.xhtml</form-login-page>`.

In order to provide a (cookie-based) "remember me" function, I have set a servlet filter which intercepts each request, checks if the user is not logged in, checks if he can be logged in automatically (via cookie), eventually logs him in using servlet based login.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CustomLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now, if the user opens his browser and connects to `mysite.com` everything just works. But if the user opens his browser and makes a straight request to something like `mysite.com/secure/secret.xhtml` I observe the following behaviour:

1. GET /secure/secret.xhtml
2. the backing beans of log-in.xhtml are instantiated (FacesContext is available)
3. the CustomLoginFilter.doFilter( ) gets called, (FacesContext is NULL)

This obviously hinders all the process. I cannot find any way to give precedence to my CustomLoginFilter over the server "declarative security filter" (or whatever); changing the web.xml order of declarations doesn't help too... any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How is it possible to execute servlet filters before any declarative security check is performed?*

That's not possible due to specification and security restrictions.

Your best bet is a hook on `preRenderView` event in the login page and use programmatic login by the new Servlet 3.0 [`HttpServletRequest#login()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

E.g.

```html
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{authenticator.checkAutoLogin}" />
```

with something like

```java
public void checkAutoLogin() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    Cookie autoLogin = externalContext.getRequestCookieMap().get("autoLoginCookieName");

    if (autoLogin != null) {
        User user = decryptCookieValueAndExtractUser(autoLogin.getValue()); // Yes, it must be encrypted! Otherwise a too easy hack.

        if (user != null) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

            try {
                request.login(user.getName(), user.getPassword());
                String originalRequestURI = externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
                externalContext.redirect(originalRequestURI != null ? originalRequestURI : "someDefaultIndex.xhtml");
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                // Login failed. It's up to you how to handle it.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `HttpServletRequest#login()` is already the underlying login method. Thanks that's a good suggestion, probably the only way to circumvent the restriction keeping things simple. *And I'd like to take the chance to personally thank you for all your quality answers and articles (I've already learned a lot from them in the previous weeks)!!*